# what is the purpose of "(jlong)(ptrdiff_t)(void*)" in heapViewer.c(a JVMTI Demo)?

Tags: heap-dump, jvmti

Below is the demo code():

```
/* Typedef to hold class details */
typedef struct {
     char *signature;
     int   count;
     int   space;
 } ClassDetails;
 ....
/* Tag this jclass */
err = (*jvmti)->SetTag(jvmti, classes[i], (jlong)(ptrdiff_t)(void*)(&details[i]));
```

the prototype of SetTag is 
    `jvmtiError SetTag(jvmtiEnv* env, jobject object,  jlong tag)`.

Can I just use it like this:
    `err = (*jvmti)->SetTag(jvmti, classes[i], (jlong)(&details[i]));` ?

Answer (score 0):

When using a tag that is a pointer, use a cast to ptrdiff_t(Standard C typedef for an integer that holds a pointer difference) to **avoid compiler warnings and errors**. 
Never use int or long, you'll find out that **int and long are not always big enough to hold a pointer**, truncating your address, where ptrdiff_t will always be big enough to hold all the bits of a pointer.
Detailed info is here [JVMPI transition to JVMTI](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/jvmpitransition-138768.html)